# Point-free functions in monadic binding

Tags: haskell, monads, pointfree

I've been investigating the usage of `>>=` with lists (when viewed as monads). In an article [All about monads](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/All_About_Monads) I found the following identity for lists: `l >>= f = concatMap f l`, where `l` is a list and `f` is some (unary) function. I tried the simple example of doubling each element of a list and arrived at the following:

```
let double :: Int -> [Int]
    double = (flip (:) []) . (2*)
let monadicCombination :: [Int]
    monadicCombination = [1,2,3,4,5] >>= double
```

I specifically wanted the `double` function to be written in a *point-free* manner. Can you think of simpler implementations of `double` so that it still can be used with `>>=`?

Comment: `double = (:[]) . (2*)`

Comment: also, `double = return . (2*)`

Comment: Yeah, the second one is probably more of what I had in mind (but didn't know how to express). Thanks @SassaNF

Comment: `return . join (+)` would work as well

Comment: For future reference, try out the `pointfree` package, which comes with a `pointfree` executable that can eta-reduce a code snippet for you.  All I did was `pointfree "double x = [2 * x]"` to get `double = return . (2 *)` and `pointfree "double x = [x + x]"` to get `double = return . join (+)`

Comment: @bheklir wow, that's two monads for the price of one question

Comment: @SassaNF I prefer the `doubleM = return . join (+)` definition simply because it can be given the more general type signature `doubleM :: (Monad m, Num a) => a -> m a`.  Now it can be used with any monad.

Comment: @bheklir I meant that `return` and `join` come from different monads, which still pricks my eyes. Even though that's not unusual.

Comment: @bheklilr But `return . (*2) :: (Monad m, Num b) => b -> m b` too

Comment: @J.Abrahamson I should go drink some coffee...

Comment: If you want to have a more general type, why not `fmap (*2) . pure`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sassa NF's `return . (*2)` is both short and demonstrates an interesting principle of your example. If we inline the whole thing we'll get

```
list >>= double
list >>= return . (*2)
```

The pattern `\f l -> l >>= return . f` Is common enough to have its own name: `liftM`

```
liftM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
liftM f m = m >>= return . f
```

And in fact, `liftM` is equivalent to `fmap`, often known as just `map` when referring to lists:

```
list >>= return . (*2)
liftM (*2) list
fmap (*2) list
map (*2) list
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful additional insights, @J.Abrahamson